# Is it possible to create a temporary stage table with table name starting with tilde(~)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am unable to create a stage table with table name starting with tilde. For eg

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY STAGE "~`tgt~`schema~`"."~src~table~_EXTERNAL";
```

This throws an error

SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:4210248694; incident 5044247.

I am able to create a table with other special characters in table name such as #. For eg

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY STAGE "~`tgt~`schema~`"."#src~table~_EXTERNAL";
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#required-parameters

It seems ~ is a valid character if the identifier is quoted. Is there anything I am missing here ?

Comment: Why do you want to use the ~ in your object name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier requirements are documented here: [identifier names](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html)

Just as an fyi, stages are not tables so there is no such thing as a "stage table"